# PHP: imagecolorat(): -1,0 is out of bounds

Tags: php, php-gd

I have this code working before (6 years ago) while upgrading to the latest PHP8, it doesn't work anymore, well it does when using absurd way putting "error_reporting(0);"

```
    $a = imagecolorat($img, $x + $dx , $y);
    $b = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y + $dy);
    $c = imagecolorat($img, $x + $dx, $y + $dy);
```

I am getting this error message.

> Notice: imagecolorat(): -1,0 is out of bounds on line 34
>
> Notice: imagecolorat(): 0,-1 is out of bounds on line 35
>
> Notice: imagecolorat(): -1,-1 is out of bounds on line 36

Do I miss something?

Comment: How are all the variables defined? It looks like some coordinates are set to negative numbers.

Comment: It process thru image per pixel.

Comment: What are the values of `$x`, `$dx`, `$y`, and `$dy`? I think "-1" would be [out of bounds](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php#120592).

Comment: the values are calculated base on the image.

Comment: $x = floor($pos[0]);
  $y = floor($pos[1]);
  $rx = $pos[0] - $x - 0.5;
  $ry = $pos[1] - $y - 0.5;
  $ax = abs($rx);
  $ay = abs($ry);
  $dx = $rx < 0 ? -1 : 1;
  $dy = $ry < 0 ? -1 : 1;
 
  $c = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
  $cx = imagecolorat($img, $x + $dx, $y);
  $cy = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y + $dy);
  $cxy = imagecolorat($img, $x + $dx, $y + $dy);

Comment: Just to be clear, a Notice is a diagnostic pointing out a possible mistake, it is not an error that stops the code running (unless you set up custom handling). Probably the code was always wrong (accessing negative coordinates) and the new version of PHP is helpfully telling you that

Comment: It's better to [edit] additional code into the question, as comments don't support the same formatting, and are designed to be temporary. Looking at the code, though, it seems straightforward enough that $x could be 0 and $dx could be -1, so $x - $dx does indeed give you an impossible coordinate.